# where do i need to put a file in web appliction so that I can read it from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I need to know where should I put a file in web application so that I could read it from servlet.

up until now, I have placed a folder named `conf/config.cfg` in the following structure

```
BankConfig/
              WEB-INF/
                       libs/
                       classes/
              conf/
                    config.cfg
```

and I'm reading it from a servlet like the following:

```
    String fileName = "conf/config.cfg";
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is =// getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        new FileInputStream(fileName);
        prop.load(is);
                }catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read it from the servlet, I would use `ServletContext` to read the file and properties.

Example:

```
String fileName = "/conf/config.cfg";
InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
prop.load(is);
```

*Note:* The `fileName` starts with a `/` (root from servlet context perspective). The only thing is I would have put the `conf/config.cfg` inside the `WEB-INF` folder (as it's hidden from view by the Servlet container, and do the same as above, instead I'll change the file name as:

```
String fileName = "/WEB-INF/conf/config.cfg";
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.ifkaar.admin.AddPoolController threw exception
 
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
 com.ifkaar.admin.AddPoolController.init(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)

Comment: it is still throwing this exception

Comment: @Ali Raza, **where** is it throwing an exception? You can't expect me to solve your error without code. I'm not telepathic *(hint: Post the code please)*.

Comment: public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
  String fileName = "/WEB-INF/conf/config.cfg";
  try {
  
  InputStream is=getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
   prop.load(is);
   this.redisHost=prop.getProperty("redis.host");
   log.info("Host :"
     + prop.getProperty("redis.host"));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }catch(NullPointerException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  this.edis=new Jedis(this.redisHost);
  
 }

Comment: Is your `/conf/config.cfg` **inside** the `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: Then debug and see what causes the `NullPointerException`.